# Why does the LLDB Debugger constantly fail to attach?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios-simulator, lldb

I have seen a lot of answers for this question:

> error: failed to attach to process ID

as **`switch to GDB`**. But no one addresses the reason of **why** it happens?

Attaching works fine with the GDB debugger but the default and recommended project setting is LLDB.

Can anybody explain why LLDB fails? Is it a common bug or am I doing something wrong?

Alternatively, how can I set GDB as my default debugger without changing it manually when creating the new projects?

System Info:

```
OS: Lion
RAM: 5GB
XCode: Version 4.6 (4H127)
Device: Mac mini
```

My localhost setting:
[image]

Comment: This is the same problem with me but it stars when I try to install some frameworks (third party) for xcode. It requirers some specific environment variable or some specific system file to be generated and after generating that file or installation my xcode start to show the same error and have to every time change the debugger to GDB for every project to compile and run it :(. It seams there is not other way then re-installing the OS X from scratch, as everything else is tried by me. All including the Xcode re-installation. And I don't think that other then the re-installation of OS X.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: On the very rare occasion that this actually happens to me, a reboot has fixed it 100% of the time. Have you tried that?

Comment: @0x7fffffff : Sometimes rebooting fixes .Some times not

Comment: Can you check if `localhost` is defined in your `/etc/hosts` file please.  From the command line `grep localhost /etc/hosts`.

Comment: # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Make sure you have `localhost` mapped to `127.0.0.1` in your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
$ grep localhost /etc/hosts
```

If `grep` doesn't show `127.0.0.1` then add it:

```
$ sudo -i
# echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts
```

<sub>^ That '#' is root's command prompt; don't type it otherwise you will comment-out the statement and nothing will happen</sub>

**NOTE**  Use `>>` and not `>`! (better is to edit it using `vi` or `mate` or whatever).

My `/etc/hosts` file shows (ignoring comments):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Comment: # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

Comment: Can you please explain this.What difference does this make?

Comment: I ll definitly try it can you verify the response i commented earlier.That is what i get

Comment: @LithuT.V It's a networking issue; lldb doesn't know how to connect to the iPhone Simulator using IPv4.  If you don't have a 127.0.0.1 <=> localhost mapping (verified by `grep`) then you will need to fix your `/etc/hosts` file using the details in this answer.

Comment: hmm?withhout a network connection cannot run simulator?:O I m a newbie .can you please explain more

Comment: @LithuT.V Don't get carried away; this doesn't mean you need an internet connection in order to debug, as 127.0.0.1 is the *loopback interface* (Google that for details) and it's simply that `lldb` (and `gdb`) uses TCP for its interprocess communication mechanism.

Comment: Updated the question :) This is my current setting

Comment: @LithuT.V Then you need to apply the fix in my answer.

Comment: @LithuT.V Great; you can award the bounty as well then.

Comment: ooh..sry .I thought marking the answer will automatically give you bounty.here you go.Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @LithuT.V No problem; glad the solution helped.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  Something must've screwed up my hosts file… I have no idea why 127.0.0.1 wasn't pointing to localhost.  Putting it back fixed the issue, though!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me, I'm trying to attach to coreaudiod, and I get the "lost connection" error :(

Answer (score 2):

Apple likes to move forward. So setting gdb as the debugger for all new projects is not an option.

Sometimes, you have to reset the [iOS Simulator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/25-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html) to clean up the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Please note I asked why not how