# Xcode 4.6 hangs on "Attaching to..." when using LLDB debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

As the title says, I'm having issues using LLDB. I've looked into this thread [Xcode 4 hangs on attaching to (App name) when debugger is set to LLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911117/xcode-4-hangs-on-attaching-to-app-name-when-debugger-is-set-to-lldb) and followed the instructions given because I'm having exactly the same issue, and managed to debug by using GDB - it works flawlessly. Anyway, i'm working in a team and I'm the only one who's having this issue, so it's a bit annoying to switch back and forward from GDB to LLDB every time i commit changes so the workaround doesn't get synchronized in the remote repository.

I've checked the compiler, and it's set to LLVM 4.2. In fact, the app compiles perfectly and gets installed in the simulator (i can execute it once I kill and restart Xcode). I would try to reinstall Xcode, but it's a mess since it's a big-sized package and I have a limit on my internet usage, it would take a long while. Does anyone know what's happening here? Is it possible that LLGB is bundled outside XCode, even if I failed to locate it on the system?

Any insight would be appreciated. I can keep the workaround going, it's just that it's a bit annoying given my personal circumstances :-)

EDIT: More details about what I mean by 'hung'. I start with Xcode open, and simulator closed (it doesn't even appear on the Dock). I click 'Run', the simulator is launched successfully, and the application shows the Splash Screen. Then xcode shows the message: "Attaching to ". And now it's hung. You can close the simulator, and xcode is still attaching. Both the Run and Stop buttons stop working. You can try to exit the application by right-clicking on the dock, you get an alert message, and from this point you can't even type code: XCode is fully hung. The only choice here is to kill XCode by using Cmd+Alt+Esc.

Comment: Does it happen when you debug on Simulator or device?

Comment: On simulator. I'll try to borrow a device asap to confirm if it happens on device too.

Comment: Might be a good idea to check the logs (/Applications/Utilities/Console.app).

Comment: @Jeepston i've confirmed this only happens when using the Simulator, it works fine on an iPhone. Thank you for the insight :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like it could be the problem some folks were seeing in [Why does the LLDB Debugger constantly fail to attach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174282/why-does-the-lldb-debugger-constantly-fail-to-attach) where they'd modified their `/etc/hosts` file so when Xcode tried to connect to debugserver via "localhost", the connection was never set up.

Comment: Dude, you're an absolute life-saver. If I could give you 10 upvotes I would :)

Answer (score 0):

When Xcode hangs, try switching to Simulator by clicking on its Dock icon. Don't use Cmd+Tab.

Comment: It's no use. The simulator runs well, i can switch between XCode and it freely, but XCode gets rendered useless.

Comment: that's the only empirical solution that I know and that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to XCode 4.6.2 fixed this issue for me